# Automatic Login using viewDidAppear does not leverage the Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I've used Parse.com to create a login / sign up flow (which works fine). On my main screen (where the user accesses the Login and Sign Up screens), I've added the following code to auto sign in every time the user opens my app:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("test", sender: self)

    }

}
```

"test" is a modal segue created from the main screen to the to a Table View Controller which is presented to the user after they Login or Sign Up.  To be clear, when the main View Controller detects that the user is logged in, it by passes the Login and Sign Up screens and goes straight to the Table View Controller.

The following is my storyboard flow:

[image: Storyboard Flow]

1: Main View Controller -> Navigation Controller 1 -> Login View Controller -> Table View Controller 1

2: Main View Controller -> Navigation Controller 2 -> Sign Up View Controller -> Table View Controller 1

The issue is this:

When the user either Logs in or Signs Up (using the respective screens), it takes them to the Table View Controller with the navigation bar at the top of the screen (this is exactly how I want it).  However, when signing into the app and the user is already logged in, when it automatically takes the user to the Table View Controller, there is no header at all.  For some reason it seems to ignore that it's a part of the Navigation Controller.

I hope the above is clear, but let me know if you need any clarification.  I know there is some issue in my storyboard setup ... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Personally i dont like your ViewCycle it should be**

1. Navigation controller
2. MainVC
3. Login Push from MainVC
4. Register Push from MainVC
5. TableList push from Login

This should be the ideal solution for your code.

And then this code will work like a Charm

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("test", sender: self)

    }

}
```

Comment: That was very helpful.  Thank you!